# Missing uses clauses in FireMonkey XE3

Tags: firemonkey

I have XE3 Installed on my machine, and am doing apps using FireMonkey 2, but there are plenty   cases where I come to the point of missing identifiers. It keeps telling me that the identifier is unknown, for most of the components I drop onto the form.

Why doesn't it add to `uses` clauses automatically, or at least, where could I find the list of packages that includes coresponding components?

For example, I can't even use `TText` component, since I can't find any info on where it lies.

Comment: Since `GetCurrentProcess` is a Windows function (located in `WinAPI.Windows`), you'll need to add that unit to the uses clause before you can use it. You can use any non-visual code in a Firemonkey app, even platform-specific ones, but you'll only be able to compile for said platform (unless you use `IFDEF`s). As for your problem regarding units not being added automatically, I've never experienced such behaviour. Typically, the unit won't be added until the first compile, but you can still work with objects from that unit prior to that. Try adding `FMX.Objects` if you're having problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will try that.
And yes, I've also noticed that some (not all) of units are automatically added when compiling, but as far as I noticed, it seems like in VCL mode only - and they're added everytime I compile. So if it comes to unknown identifier, I just compile it, and it repairs itself. But not in Firemonkey. I know, it is crossplatform mode, so I'd need to specify Windows functions manualy, but I'm pretty sure there is or should be a way of telling that only once, not constantly...

Comment: Yep, looks like FMX.Objects did the trick with the TText component and  few others. Not solving all of my problems, but seems like a good way to go. At least a clue to what's goin' on. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the text of the item it complains about and click F1 for help, the help page will tell you the parent object which you can then add to the uses clause.